# Need help getting OTP to work on OpenVPN Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, openvpn, google-authenticator

I've searched everywhere and can't find a good answer. Here's my situation:

I have Ubuntu 18.04 which comes with OpenVPN.
I have a .ovpn file that I will use to connect to the correct server.

The server requires One Time Password authentication, using the Google Authenticator smartphone app.

**HOW** do I configure the OpenVPN client on Ubuntu 18.04, to provide support for the Google Authenticator app?

A step by step would be amazing.

Thanks a lot!

Kind regards,
Maarten